# Gwt "Double" cell-widget number formatting

Tags: gwt, double, cell, number-formatting

I have this in my uiBinder:

Declared as @UiField ValueBoxEditorDecorator importoEditor; in my code.

It behaves correctly: "50" displays as "50.0".
Now I want to display it as "50.00", since it is a currency euro value.

How can I set a number formatter on that field?

Answer (score 0):

Use GWT's **NumberFormat**...

For setting...

```
String value = "50.00";    
double valueAsDouble = NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().parse(value);
```

For getting...

```
double paramValue = 50.00;
String result = NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().format(paramValue);
```

NumberFormat has lots of other convenient static methods, like getCurrencyFormat, that respect locale.  Check it out!